# How nextTick API works in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, event-loop

In vue's source code, nexttick uses mircotask to run callback function.

Q1: Why this can work? When DOM will be freshed, after microtask queue is empty?

In case of promise is not supported, vue will use marcotask instead?

Q2: If microtask and macrotask can both do this, why not just use macrotask?

quote: [necttick source code](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/core/util/next-tick.js)